# SAML 2.0: Solicited vs Unsolicited SSO

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

I am a SP developing SAML 2.0 capability for SSO.

The SSO will ALWAYS be initiated from the IdP (Users will get to my site from their Enterprise Portal, where they are already signed in).

So, what I am trying to understand is whether I should just offer unsolicited (IdP initiated) SSO, or is it still best practice to develop solicited (SP initiated) SSO. If the latter, then why do I need the added complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When, as you suggest, users will always be initiated from the IDP - and in fact every IDP that the SP is connected to - then there's no need to add SP initiated SSO support to your SP.

Of course one may argue that having support for SP initiated SSO is more generic and a superset of IDP initiated SSO because you would be able to trigger SSO from outside the IDP portal as well as include SP initiated SSO links in your Enterprise Portal. But in your case the former would never be required so you may stick with IDP initiated SSO only, assuming that all connected IDPs support that.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for the response. You say 'assuming that all connected IDPs support that'. Is it common that IDPs only support SP initiated SSO? Any 'gut intuition' on the % of Enterprises that wouldn't support IdP initiated SSO?

Comment: educated guess: 1%, but you will just have to verify with the actual IDPs

Answer (score 1):

SP-initiated SSO *is* best practise in general, and [OWASP states that](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SAML_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#unsolicited-response-ie-idp-initiated-sso-considerations-for-service-providers) "Unsolicited Response is inherently less secure by design due to the lack of CSRF protection."